# how to navigate to login after successful registration in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to redirect to the login screen after a successful registration in react native but its now working and giving an error.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'navigation.navigate')

Here is my code:

```
function SignupScreen({ navigation }) {
  const registerApi = useApi(usersApi.register);

  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async (userInfo) => {
    const result = await usersApi.register(userInfo);
    console.log(result.data);
    if (!result.ok) {
      if (result.data) setError(result.data.error);
      else {
        setError("An unexpected error occurred.");
        console.log(result);
      }
      return;
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        "Registeration Succesfull",
        "Verification email has been sent. kindly check your email and login with your credendtials",
        [
          {
            text: "Ok",
            onPress: () => navigation.navigate("Login"),
          },
        ]
      );
    }
  };
```

I'm new in react native

Comment: Have you created navigation stack in any of starting file like index.js or app.js ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda yes i have created stack navigator in separate file where is created stack navigator with login and signup screen

Comment: `navigation` is not getting passed to the `SignUpScreen`. Could you show how you pass the props?

Comment: @yudhiesh on startup i simply rendered <SignupScreen/>

Comment: @barbiequeen you need to render your navigator in the entry point. Not the `SignupScreen`

Comment: @barbiequeen please include the code with the Stack Navigator.

Comment: Yes, just set your navigation stack to render, and set the signup screen above all other screen, it will automatically render signup screen first.

Comment: Thanks All its working now. before i was not passing navigation as i was rendering online <Signup Screen /> not Stack Navigator